# get title (name) of currently running QUnit test

Tags: javascript, qunit

I would like to log a quick separator to the console in each QUnit test like this:

```
test( "hello test", function() {
    testTitle = XXX; // get "hello test" here
    console.log("========= " + testTitle + "==============");
    // my test follows here
});
```

How can I get the title (maybe also called "name") of the test?

Comment: Please make sure to avoid the scenario where you run the tests and then you need to read the logs to know if they passed or not. This bypasses most of the benefits of automated testing! If the logs are just to provide extra information then no problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [callbacks of QUnit](http://api.qunitjs.com/category/callbacks/). They are called at several different points during the execution of the tests (e.g. before each test, after each module, ...)

Here is an example from my test suite:

```js
QUnit.begin = function() {
    console.log('####');
};

QUnit.testStart = function(test) {
    var module = test.module ? test.module : '';
    console.log('#' + module + " " + test.name + ": started.");
};

QUnit.testDone = function(test) {
    var module = test.module ? test.module : '';
    console.log('#' + module + " " + test.name + ": done.");
    console.log('####');
};
```

It put this in a file called `helper.js` and include it on the test index.html page.

It produces output like this:

```
####
#kort-Availability Includes: started.
#kort-Availability Includes: done.
#### 
#kort-UrlLib Constructor: started.
#kort-UrlLib Constructor: done.
#### 
#kort-UrlLib getCurrentUrl: started.
#kort-UrlLib getCurrentUrl: done. 
####
```

Comment: This was fantastically helpful for me, to test a QUnit test generator! :) Thanks.

Comment: The QUnit [callbacks](https://api.qunitjs.com/callbacks/QUnit.begin) now need to be set up by calling `begin(func)` etc, rather than assigning to `begin` etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to use this solution :

```
test( "hello test", function(assert) {
  testTitle = assert.test.testName; // get "hello test" here
  console.log("========= " + testTitle + "==============");
  // my test follows here
});
```

========= hello test==============

Answer (score 0):

You should try `Javascript`'s `arguments` object (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)):

```
test( "hello test", function() {
    testTitle = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0]; // get "hello test" here
    console.log("========= " + testTitle + "==============");
    // my test follows here
});
```

**EDIT:**
I have created a small (and documented) [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc8fs/) of how it should work.
Notice that my answer is a pure `JavaScript` one and is true no only for `QUnit`.

Comment: does not work, `arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0]` is 'undefined'

Comment: I am not sure as to why it didn't work for you, it should. check: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc8fs/

Comment: It does not work because of the specific way that QUnit calls test(). So it works in general, yes, but not in this very QUnit situation. Anyway, I got the proper solution now :) Nonetheless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

QUnit.config.current is an Object contains the currently running test. So you can show it, like console.log(QUnit.config.current). There are many paramters of this object(testName, started..) you can change them.

```
QUnit.test("some test", function() {
  console.log( QUnit.config.current.testName);
});
```

Comment: I have come across this answer after it _was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content_. Please don't just "dump" code, but rather provide an explanation of what the code does and why it should work.

Comment: QUnit.config.current is an Object contains the currently running test. So you can show it, like 
console.log(QUnit.config.current). There are many paramters of this object(testName, started..) you can change them.

Comment: would you please edit this information into your answer?